# Findbugs fails with "java.io.IOException: No files to analyze could be opened"

Tags: android, android-studio, findbugs, gradlew, android-studio-2.1

I run an Android Studio v2.1.3 and use `./gradlew build` to detect errors in the Android project with the Findbags.

Recently an error started to come up:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':process:customFindbugs'.
> java.io.IOException: No files to analyze could be opened
```

There are enough disk space and RAM and beside that I don't see any particular reason for that error to occur. Please help to elaborate on this problem.

Comment: I've updated to the Android Studio to 2.2.2, gradle to 2.2.2, gradle wrapper to 2.14.1. The problem is still arising from time to time.

Answer (score 8):

If you use 3.2, please take a note that

```
classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes")
```

should be

```
classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac")
```

Comment: This solved it for me, thanks! I bumped into this issue after upgrading my project to v3.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after reorganizing my gradle files.
This is the actual command:

```
gradlew --stacktrace assemble findbugs
```

Accidentally, I did this:

```
gradlew --stacktrace findbugs
```

With the first command no error arises, with later it shows "java.io.IOException: No files to analyze could be opened".
To cut a long story short, maybe your files weren't compiled (yet).

Comment: That could be the right direction to look at. I use Dagger2 and that means there are classes generated as the project is assembled.

Comment: Ah ok, try to work with dependsOn: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks