# Minimal working SpotBugs setup for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, spotbugs

How do I set up SpotBugs for Android?

I tried following the [official documentation](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gradle.html) and that of the [gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.spotbugs), but the setup for Android is incomplete and confusing, and didn't work.

I tried the following setup.

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // ...
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:1.6.4"
  }
}
```

build.gradle (app):

```
//...
apply plugin: "com.github.spotbugs"

android {
  // ...
  sourceSets {
    main {
      java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
  }
}

// ...

spotbugs {
    toolVersion = "3.1.3"
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/findbugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
}

tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
  // What do I need to do here?
}
```

I tried running it with `./gradlew spotbugsMain`, but the gradle task is missing.
Am I supposed to add the task manually? How do I do that?

Could you show me an example of a minimal working setup for an Android project?

Comment: If the downvoters would tell me why, I could improve the question.

Comment: @Terry Your question seems perfectly fine to me, and I don't understand why anyone has down voted it. Even more bizarre is that two people have voted to close a question about how to configure SpotBugs for Android as "off topic"!

Comment: Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/mik9/fdde79052fef7f03c4325734701a39d7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I made some tests on my side and I manage to make it work like this :

1) Move the `sourceSets` declaration outside the `android` block. Leave it empty, it's just for the `spotbugsMain` task generation, it won't impact the global Android build.

```
android {
   // ...
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = []
    }
}
```

2) Keep your `spotbugs` block and configure the `SpotBugsTask` tasks like this :

```
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
    classes = files("$projectDir.absolutePath/build/intermediates/classes/debug")
    source = fileTree('src/main/java')
}
```

It will generate reports in `app/build/findbugsReports`

**Important :**

It only works with the `./gradlew build` command, `./gradlew spotbugsMain` won't work as the project must be built before

You can fix that adding an `assemble` dependency :

```
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask) {
    dependsOn 'assemble'
    classes = files("$projectDir.absolutePath/build/intermediates/classes/debug")
    source = fileTree('src/main/java')
}
```

Comment: I give up. I can't get it to work with gradle 6 (plugin v 4.5)

Answer (score 9):

Following on from ToYonos answer (9 October 2018); Use this for Android Studio 3.4 and above:

### project/build.gradle

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https:// maven url 1'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" // Add this, for SpotBugs
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath '...'

        // If you're using gradle 6.x, add this to use SpotBugs app version 4.0.2
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.spotbugs.snom:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:4.3.0"

        // If you're using gradle 4.x or 5.x, add this to use SpotBugs app version 3.1.2
        classpath "com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-gradle-plugin:2.0.1" 
    }
}
```

### project/app/build.gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: '...'
apply plugin: "com.github.spotbugs" // <- Add this
    
dependencies {
    ...
}

// This block is only needed for gradle 4/5 only.
// It's for SpotBugs to create a 'spotbugsMain' gradle task.
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = []
    }
}
    
spotbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("$project.buildDir/SpotBugsReports")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
}

// Note: gradle 4/5 should use "com.github.spotbugs.SpotBugsTask"
tasks.withType(com.github.spotbugs.snom.SpotBugsTask) {
    dependsOn 'assembleDebug'
    classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac") // Important to use this path
    excludeFilter = file("$project/spot-bugs-exclude.xml") // Optional - Explained below
    source = fileTree('src/main/java') // Only needed on gradle 4/5
    reports {
        // Enable HTML report only
        html.enabled = true
        xml.enabled = false
    }
}
```

You can generate a report for your debug build by running the gradle task:

> For gradle 6.x: **`./gradlew spotbugsDebug`**

> For gradle 5 or 4: **`./gradlew spotbugsMain`**

It's important to use `classes = files("$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac")` , otherwise you'll get an error `"java.io.IOException: No files to analyze could be opened"` -- see [Findbugs fails with "java.io.IOException: No files to analyze could be opened"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851965/findbugs-fails-with-java-io-ioexception-no-files-to-analyze-could-be-opened)

You'll also need to enable the HTML report and disable XML report, to see a human-readable format.

`ignoreFailures = true` is optional. When SpotBugs detects a code warning, by default it will end with `"BUILD FAILED"` + a report file. Setting `ignoreFailures = true` means the gradle task will end with `"BUILD SUCCESSFUL"` + a report file.

To exclude some generated classes from the analysis, setup an `excludeFilter`. For a sample exclude file, check [here](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html#complete-example) or [here (same as findbugs-exclude.xml)](https://dev.to/onmyway133/how-to-setup-android-projects-11pn)

More information and tutorial here: https://mikedemaso.com/tech/2020-06-10-spotbugs-gradle-plugin-android/